# Can I preload belongsTo parent models in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm getting a large batch of 1000 records that I need to loop through in my view. I get them by doing something like:

```
$children = Child::all();
```

And in my view, I do something like this:

```
@foreach($children as $child)
  {{ $child->parent->name }}
@endforeach
```

The problem is, this executes 1000 queries. Is there a way for me to make use of the belongsTo method relationship without this massive loss of efficiency?

Comment: you're looking for [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use eager loading using `with`:

```
$children = Child::with('parent')->all();
```

Now only one extra query should be launched to get `parent` relation.